# Drawing LinearLayout view on canvas disappearing

Tags: java, android, camera, android-canvas, surfaceview

I'm drawing linearlayout views (insertpoint) on a Surface View Camera using canvas. I'm facing a problem when there are too many views (ex: 40 in my case), some views are disappearing on moving the camera. I'm unable to find the issue here. Is there any issue with the setX and setY method? You can see my code below and please respond to it.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (currentLocation == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < places.size(); i++) {
         float[] currentLocationInECEF = LocationHelper.WSG84toECEF(currentLocation);
         float[] pointInECEF = LocationHelper.WSG84toECEF(poiLoc.get(i));
         float[] pointInENU = LocationHelper.ECEFtoENU(currentLocation, currentLocationInECEF, pointInECEF);

        Matrix.multiplyMV(cameraCoordinateVector, 0, rotatedProjectionMatrix, 0, pointInENU, 0);


        if (cameraCoordinateVector[2] < 0 && insertPoint!=null && insertPoint.getChildAt(i)!=null) {
            float x = (0.5f + cameraCoordinateVector[0] / cameraCoordinateVector[3]) * canvas.getWidth();
            float y = (0.5f - cameraCoordinateVector[1] / cameraCoordinateVector[3]) * canvas.getHeight();

            insertPoint.getChildAt(i).setX(x - (insertPoint.getChildAt(i).getWidth()/2));
            insertPoint.getChildAt(i).setY(y);
            insertPoint.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Expected result: All the views should appear on the Camera View.
Actual Result: Some views are disappearing on moving the Camera and onDrawCanvas callback.

I'm using this library https://github.com/dat-ng/ar-location-based-android

[image]

Comment: what are you doing?

Comment: add some screenshots

Comment: @pembaTamang I have added the screenshot. I'm trying to add linearlayouts as views on a Camera but views are becoming half and even disappearing fully when moving the camera.

Comment: looks fine. Mabye you are running out of memory.
Btw my colleage uses this and it works properly
https://github.com/appoly/ARCore-Location

Comment: Thanks but its not a memory issue i guess. I want to achieve this without using any SDK. Is there any other way I can fix the views on Camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to fixed the issue. All I had to do is replace LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout and it worked like a charm.